# Errors with figure caption since using siunitx

Tags: captions, subfloats, siunitx

I am a bit of a newbie with LaTeX. Everything was working well (mostly) but I am running into all sorts of weird errors since I added the `siunitx` package. 
The error log first showed errors with tables, which I was able to fix (I think) using a quick tip on [entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/tabular-siunitx-and-input-extra-or-forgotten) (thank you). Now the remaining errors originate from all my figure captions. It feels like `siunitx` is trying to parse my figure captions but is rejecting their content. I tried the same strategy as what fixed it for my tables (`\sisetup{parse-numbers = false}`), but it is still not working. Any ideas?

This is my simple code (works if **siunitx** is commented out):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
%
% Review cuthesis.sty for more documentation on available options
% for this package.
%\usepackage[1committee,phd,nonsequential]{cuthesis}
\usepackage[3committee,masters,standard,nonsequential]{cuthesis} %Carleton University template
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{siunitx} %used for the writing of SI units such as micro
\usepackage{hyperref} %used for pdf properties
%\usepackage[indent,bf]{caption}

\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\onehalfspacing

\title{Sandbox}

\begin{document}

% Define thesis title and author
\title{RD}
\author{FD}
\pastdegrees{B.Eng.}
\dept{Systems and Computer Engineering}
\degreename{Master of Applied Science in Electrical Engineering}


% Specify your Thesis Submission Date
\submitdate{May, 2012} \copyrightyear{2012} \copyrightmonth{May}

% Thesis committee information for the signature page
% Be sure to specify size of committee in cuthesis options.
% Department Chair does not count as a committee member.
% ie: 1committee = department chair  (doesn't make sense)
%     2committee = firstcommittee + department chair
%     3committee = firstcommittee + secondcommittee + department chair
%     4committee = firstcommittee + secondcommittee + thirdcommittee + department chair
% Default setting is 1committee
\firstcommittee{Professor MS, Thesis Supervisor}
\secondcommittee{Professor MB, Examiner}
\thirdcommittee{Professor "Name", Thesis Co-supervisor}

% Specify department chair
\departmentchair{Professor HS, Chair,\\Department of Systems and Computer Engineering}


\section{whatever}
la la

\begin{figure}
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx} 
  %TODO regenerate this graph with matlab
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4in]{OFDMspectrum-single.png}
  \caption{Spectrum of a single modulated OFDM subcarrier (truncated).}  \label{fig:single}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide a full working minimal example. I use siunitx and the caption package and in my very large documents with ~100 packages I have no problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: In addition to a MWE, a full log would be useful: there was an issue some time ago with `expl3` which had similar symptoms.

Comment: MWE posted above. Log is too big. How can I add it in a comment? What if I answer my own question?

Comment: @Fred That's not minimal: you load packages which I doubt cause the issue. Usually a log for a MWE will be fine for posting here. It is fine to answer your own question.

Comment: I removed most of the packages and I can then successfully compile with the caption. The trouble is to iron out which package specifically is incompatible. Suspect http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/dansereau/cuthesis.zip. More to follow.

Comment: The one package is indeed the cause of the error. How can I troubleshoot the incompatibility between the two?

Comment: What if the package I am using is numbering the tables and figures in a specific way, and that is causing the numbers to be parsed by siunitx which dislikes what it sees?

Comment: The incompatibility of `cuthesis` and `calc` was pointed out in [caption works in one file but not another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31633/4301).

Comment: Based on Peter's comment, shall I close this as a dupe?

Answer (score 3):

(This is a bit too long for a comment.)

If you work through to create a MWE, the problem can be isolated to a document consisting of

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cuthesis}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Demo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The **calc** package is entirely standard, so this is a bug in **cuthesis**.

(The problem shows up with **siunitx** as it loads **calc**.)

Comment: The incompatibility of `cuthesis` and `calc` was pointed out in [caption works in one file but not another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31633/4301).

Comment: placing \usepackage{calc} at the top of my document, right before the \usepackage{cuthesis} works well as a workaround. It precedes the call to the same package in {siunitx}. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: @PeterGrill Good fine: This is probably a dupe, then